# Java - when changing from jre 1.6 to 1.7 DocumentBuildFactory fails

Tags: java, java-7, xerces, jaxp

I am trying to change a project to work on jre 1.7. But when I change the referenced library, I get an error with the following:

```
DocumentBuildFactory documentBuildFactory = (DocumentBuilderFactory) = new  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl();
```

Any ideas why? as I didn't think it was deprecated.

The error I am getting is org.apache.xerces cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: isn't it `DocumentBuilderFactory`?

Comment: added error - that was just a typo in the qn - sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't instantiate an `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl` directly. Always use [`DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance%28%29), which will use (among other things) the Services API to locate the actual `DocumentBuilderFactory` to instantiate.